# How to use code folding with Aquamacs?

Tags: auctex, aquamacs, code-folding

I would like to use code folding with Aquamacs but I don't find any reference to do it. I would like to fold the figure and the paragraph. I've already tried all the combination listed [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Folding). Can anybody give my a practical example to fold this code? And a `\section`.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fiocco}
   \caption{A running dog}
    \label{fig:fiocc}
\end{figure}
```

I've used <kbd>C-c</kbd>,<kbd>C-o</kbd>,<kbd>C-r</kbd> but it doesn't work....

Comment: To fold the `figure` environment use `C-C C-o C-e` with point inside that environment.

Comment: @giordano this works, so I can undo this using C-c C-o p. I can fold automatically all the figure? For the section seems I have to do something else...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to customize [`TeX-fold-env-spec-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dfold_002denv_002dspec_002dlist) (`LaTeX-fold-env-spec-list` is more appropriate but the result is just the same if you use only LaTeX and not plain TeX).  In your init file add this code

```lisp
(add-to-list 'TeX-fold-env-spec-list '("[figure]" ("figure")))
```

Then with <kbd>C-c C-o C-b</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`TeX-fold-buffer`<kbd>RET</kbd>) all `figure` environments in the current buffer will be folded at once.  To fold only `figure` environments in the current paragraph use <kbd>C-c C-o C-p</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`TeX-fold-paragraph`<kbd>RET</kbd>).

The folding of paragraphs is done using the [outline minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Outline-Mode) (see also the [Outlining the Document](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Outline) section in AUCTeX manual).  You can activate it with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`outline-minor-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> and then use the `Outline` menu.

Comment: Thank a lot, can I do the same with \section and \subsection?

Comment: @GM see the updated answer.

Comment: @GM did you see the updated answer?  Is it complete now?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot I've voted up you, usually I wait always a week to accept answer, don't worry I will soon do it!